# Нужна ли запятая в контексте?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы

Предложение: «Наиболее близкие к России аналогичные образцы исламской архитектуры, как, впрочем, и реконструкцию молитвенного кружения дервишей, сегодня можно увидеть лишь в Турции и Египте». Интересует вопрос постановки запятой перед словом «сегодня». Нужна ли она там?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая перед "сегодня" нужна: она закрывает сравнительный оборот с сочетанием "как и", в которое попросту вклинивается вводное слово "впрочем", см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8/).

> **Запятыми** выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты с союзом *как* в случаях, если оборот начинается сочетанием *как и*: К *Москве,*  **как и ко всей стране,** *я чувствую свою сыновность, как к старой няньке* (Пауст.); *В её глазах,*  **как и во всём лице,** *было что-то необычное*; *Дети,*  **как и взрослые,**  *должны быть приучены к соблюдению правил общежития*;  **Как и на прошлогодних соревнованиях,** *впереди оказались спортсмены Российской Федерации.*

Поэтому верно так.

*Наиболее близкие к России аналогичные образцы исламской архитектуры, как, впрочем, и реконструкцию молитвенного кружения дервишей, сегодня можно увидеть лишь в Турции и Египте.*